# How to call a C++ function which returns a vector of doubles from Python?

Tags: python, c++

I have a C++ function with the following signature:

```
vector<double> fun(char *);
```

I want to call this function from Python and use the return value as a Python list. For void function I know how to do it using SWIG. But I don't know how to do it for functions returning vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SWIG `.i` file you can include any standard `std::vector<T>` type like so:

```
%include "std_vector.i"

namespace std {
    %template(DoubleVector) vector<double>;
}
```